# redirect an iframe

Tags: php, iframe

is it possible to redirect an iframe to display the content of the frame after 2 seconds in a full window(same window, not a new one). I hope for a PHP solution.

Comment: PHP can't interact with frames. I don't understand your question. Do you want the parent frame to update itself with a child-frame's contents?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a client side language for that - namely JavaScript.

Here's a start

```
setTimeout(function() {

    var frameElement = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
    // get iframe URL
    // window.open(iFrameUrl, '_self');

}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the location property of the 'top' object in JavaScript.

[This link](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/jsFrames.htm) seems to describe this approach more fully.